# Си, операторы сравнения ">=", "<=" для строк, зачем?

Tags: c

Зачем в Си можно сравнивать строки с строками или числами при помощи "<=", ">=", ">", "<", что это дает?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[5] = "tests";
    printf("%i", c <= "12345"); // 1
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то, в Си нет строк. В интересующих вас операциях сравниваются указатели (т.е. числа, которые адресуют память)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот вопрос мне показался весьма примечательным. С одной стороны, вопрос про одну из базовых операций языка. И приведен простенький наглядный пример. А с другой стороны, в этом примере задействуется целая куча неявных правил. Причем правил, контроль над исполнением которых возложен на программиста, а нарушение которых может вызывать в программе полный швах.

Как заметили в комментариях, в таком контексте (да и в случае других арифметических операций) массив (коим являются C-style строки) *неявно* преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент, а затем эти два указателя сравниваются. Однако тут есть еще один нюанс - С допускает сравнение указателей на элемент массивов только с указателями на другие элементы этого же массива и с указателем на фиктивный элемент, который мог бы располагаться стазу после последнего элемента в массиве. Во всех остальных случаях поведение не определено.

> **6.5.8 Relational operators**
>   5 When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object or incomplete types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

Что касается сравнения строк / массивов с числами, то такая операция в С не определена вообще. Сравнение разрешается только в 3 случаях:

> 2 One of the following shall hold:
>   — both operands have real type;
>   — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object
>   types; or
>   — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible
>   incomplete types.

Хотя компилятор [почти без возражений компилирует аналогичный пример](https://godbolt.org/z/MEgZPV):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%i", 1 <= "12345");
}
```